# QT5 - multiple OpenGL widgets in the same window

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, qt4, qt5

I have developed a basic graphical engine monitoring application using OpenGL ES. It draws basic 2D geometry. I am interested in porting this to QT5 for the cross-platform comparability.

I want to turn each gauge into an individual widget with it's own signals and slots. QT provides a nice [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html) of how to make an OpenGL widget. However, this method makes a new window for each widget. It there a method to make each gauge it's own widget and draw them all in the same window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QOpenGLWidget is a widget so you can place it inside another widget, in the example when creating a single widget this will be the window. You can create some QMainWindow, QDialog or QWidget and place within them a QOpenGLWidget, the following is an example of how to do it, just replace this main to the main example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#ifndef QT_NO_OPENGL
#include "mainwidget.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    app.setApplicationName("cube");
    app.setApplicationVersion("0.1");
#ifndef QT_NO_OPENGL
    QDialog w;
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(&w);
    QHBoxLayout *hlay = new QHBoxLayout;
    hlay->addWidget(new MainWidget(&w));
    hlay->addWidget(new MainWidget(&w));
    QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout;
    vlay->addLayout(hlay);
    vlay->addWidget(new MainWidget(&w));
    lay->addWidget(new MainWidget(&w));
    lay->addLayout(vlay);
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();
#else
    QLabel note("OpenGL Support required");
    note.show();
#endif
    return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Would it make more sense to just redraw all of these using QT Quick since they are basic 2D shapes?

Comment: @user8908459 Qt Quick is different from Qt C ++, they are one of the several options that Qt gives, so the answer could be: if you want to do it, then do it. On the other hand if my answer was helpful do not forget to mark it as correct.